# Drupal 8 installation error - missing PHP extensions dom, simpleXML, XML

Tags: xml, dom, drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to install Drupal 8 on an Ubuntu LAMP droplet on Digital Ocean and as I'm going through the install process, I ran into the following error within the Requirements portion of the install saying that PHP Extensions need to be enabled for dom, SimpleXML, xml.

Not really sure how to go about enabling this, any insight or direction would be appreciated. (If it helps, the web server is Apache/2.4.29 and the version of PHP is 7.2.24)

Error:

**PHP EXTENSIONS**

Disabled

Drupal requires you to enable the PHP extensions in the following list (see the system requirements page for more information):

- dom
- SimpleXML
- xml

---

[image: Image of the error message I received]

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install php-xml` to install the extensions